# MKAnnotationView pin wont appear

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I am new with MapKit and all its functionalities and therefore, stuck at trying to display a pin. I followed an online video tutorial on how to find user current location and drop a pin there. But when I typed the method for the pin, I do not get it at all. I would like to know where did I go wrong for this.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Location";
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    NSLog(@"Annotation view run");
    MKPinAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    pin.animatesDrop = YES;
    return pin;
}

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

// once location is determined, center to that location.
location = newLocation.coordinate;
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center = location;

MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 0.003;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.003;
region.span = span;

[mapView setRegion:region animated:FALSE];
```

}

Any advice of where I done wrong would be great!

Comment: is "Annotation view run" ever displayed in your log?

Comment: nope, the method wasnt even called.

Comment: Have you set MKMapViewDelegate in .h file?

Comment: yes i have, including the CLLocationManagerDelegate too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your method is never got invoked, you should do:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    [aMapView removeAnnotation:[self point]];
    mkShape.coordinate = aMapView.centerCoordinate;
    [aMapView addAnnotation:mkShape];
}
```

And you should create your MKAnnotationView properly.
You need create two properties in .h file first (for performance reason):

```
MKPointAnnotation *mkShape;
MKAnnotationView *annotationView;
```

then use the code below to create your MKPointAnnotation

```
- (void)createShape
{
    if (!mkShape) {
        mkShape = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        mkShape.title = nil;
        mkShape.subtitle = @"test description";
    }
}

- (id <MKAnnotation>)point
{
    [self createShape];

    // Make sure to check if this is an MKPointAnnotation.  MKOverlays also
    // conform to MKAnnotation, so it isn't sufficient to just check to
    // conformance to MKAnnotation.
    if ([mkShape isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
        return (id <MKAnnotation>)mkShape;

    return nil;
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
{
    if (!annotationView) {
        id <MKAnnotation> annotation = [self point];
        if (annotation) {
            MKPinAnnotationView *pin =
            [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
            pin.canShowCallout = YES;
            pin.animatesDrop = YES;
            pin.draggable = NO;
            annotationView = pin;
        }
    }
    return annotationView;
}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isEqual:mkShape]) {
        return [self annotationView];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

At the end, don't forget to release your properties.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [annotationView release];
    [mkShape release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: dose mapView:viewForAnnotation: get invoked? If you are using Simulator to test your code, try move the map by yourself, and wait to see if the method is invoked.

Comment: BTW, have you ever set your mapView.delegate? I can't find where you set it in your code.

Comment: 1st comment: no, it does not get invoked. and I didn't know that moving the map may invoke it, will try again now

2nd comment: yes, I hope I did it correctly in the .h file. I declared the MKMApViewDelegate in the interface, is that correct? or do I have to do a mapView.delegate = self; ?

Comment: yes, you have to add mapView.delegate = self; to let the mapView understand where is the delegate.

Comment: then what is the meaning of declaring the MKMapViewDelegate in the .h?

Comment: It just let the compiler knows your class has the ability to handle the delegate methods. You should also let the mapView knows who is its delegate.

Comment: yeap! the mapView.delegate = self; worked wonders! but now, the damn pin isnt showing up still! The viewForAnnotation is called but the pin isnt displayed.

Comment: - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    [aMapView removeAnnotation:[self point]];
    mkShape.coordinate = aMapView.centerCoordinate;
    [aMapView addAnnotation:mkShape];
}

Comment: Add the codes below into your viewDidLoad method and see if it shows up. 
    [mapView removeAnnotation:[self point]];
    mkShape.coordinate = mapView.centerCoordinate;
    [mapView addAnnotation:mkShape];

Comment: ok, I finally understood why it didnt work. My Xcode 4 simulator cant really run the MapKit well, I deployed it onto my device and it worked. Everything :P  so thanks for your help!