# Can't make MKannotate pin show up on my map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkannotation

Right now I am trying to test the concept of annotating a pin on a map before I complete the rest of my assignment. The assignment instructions says that a CLLocationManager is not needed. So far I have tried invoking the mkAnnotate pin on a specific instance of my MKannotate class. I have tried invoking a delegate method and I have tried manually entering the coordinates without success. Later in the assignment I want to make the program drop a pin a zoom to a location based on the selection of a segmented button, but right now I just want to figure out how to drop a pin. Over here is the code in my ViewContoller.m file

```
#import "GoThereViewController.h"

@interface GoThereViewController ()

@end

@implementation GoThereViewController
//@synthesize segment;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [world setShowsUserLocation:YES]; 

    //Location array declarations
    //GoThereMapPoint *gtET = [[GoThereMapPoint alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.774033,-86.172754) title:@"Engineering & Technology Building"];
    GoThereMapPoint *gtEmpireState = [[GoThereMapPoint alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.7483786347046,-73.98555994033813) title:@"Empire State Building"];  
    GoThereMapPoint *gtTajMahal = [[GoThereMapPoint alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.171171855453526,78.04248690605164) title:@"Taj Mahal"];


    //Put in array.
    //aryGoThere = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:gtET,gtEmpireState,gtTajMahal, nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


//Somehow this method calls the annotate and zoom method
-(void)didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
              fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    GoThereMapPoint *gtET = [[GoThereMapPoint alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.774033,-86.172754) title:@"Engineering & Technology Building"];    
    [self foundLocation:newLocation];
}

//Create instance of location and zoom to it
-(void)foundLocation:(CLLocation *)loc
{
    //Create instance of location
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [loc coordinate];
    //Add pin

    GoThereMapPoint *mp = [[GoThereMapPoint alloc]initWithCoordinate:coord title:@"test"]; 
     [world addAnnotation:mp];    //Zoom to location
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord,500,500);
    [world setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

If there is anything else you need in order to help please be sure to let me know.

EDIT:Forgot to mention the name of the MKAnnotate class is GoThereViewController.

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022411/mkannotationview-pin-wont-appear

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the the `updateLocations` method is actually being called. That method is deprecated right now in favor of:

`- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
}`

You should be calling the `foundLocation` method from there.